# How to close a chrome browser tab via terminal?

Tags: bash, shell, google-chrome, sh

Currently I am writing a script that invokes a new instance of the `chrome` browser.

I know how to call chrome to open a `*.html` document in a new tab.

```
google-chrome *.html
```

Chrome will open a new tab to show that file.

How can I close the tab in terminal without closing other tabs or closing the browser window?

Answer (score 1):

> only linux answer:

Perhaps wmctrl could be of some assistance. You could use the -c option that closes a window gracefully:

```
wmctrl -c "tab title"
```

The string chrome is matched against the window titles. Note that the window might not close if some message pops-up (e.g. when you have multiple tabs open).

Comment: I used `wmctrl -c "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20441793/how-to-close-a-chrome-browser-tab-via-terminal"` and this tab stayed open. I don't think it works....

Comment: Tab tile means the Title of the page itself not the URL in the address bar.
For example page `http://example.org` Title: `Example page`. So use `wmctrl -c "Example page"`

Comment: this doesn't work at all. where do you get `wmctrl` from ??

Comment: @lacostenycoder I've taken it from here https://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl and the reason it may not work for you is that yout have to write `wmctrl -c "Tab title"` not the url. It is a only-linux solution, because the question is tagged "bash"

Comment: @Liam MacOS supports bash so this still is not a universal answer, although there appears to be a homebrew install.  how do you get the actual tab name? on current versions it's often hidden.

Comment: you can get the tab name from the meta tag in the html @lacostenycoder

Comment: @Liam tried with `brew install wmctrl` it doesn't work on MacOS. You should update your answer that it only is for linux systems.

Comment: even on linux this only works on closing "window" with tab title, not the tab

Answer (score 1):

You can look into chrome remote debugging:

```
chromium --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

and connect to it with some kind of client ( https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-remote-interface seems good). The debug protocol is used for a number of applications, but with some work you can achieve the kind of functionality you want. Here are some docs for you to check out: https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page

Or perhaps chromix-too, which is based on an extension, daemon and client architecture.

https://github.com/smblott-github/chromix-too

This seems to be much easier to use, and might be exactly what you want, though the extension is a bit inconvenient, and there seems to be demand for more capabilities to be supported.

**EDIT** The query you would be looking for is:

```
        const chrome = require('ox-chrome-remote-interface'); 
        chrome.List().then(tabs=>{
            const list = tabs
                .filter(t=>t.type == 'page' &&  t.title.includes(TITLE))
                .map(t => t.id)
            if(list.length==1){
                chrome.Close({id:list[0]})
            } else {
                console.error(`${list.length} tabs match.`)
            }
        })
```