# how implement auth0 authentication using external browser(chrome,firefox etc.) in electron application

Tags: electron, auth0

I am using using auth0 authentication in my electron app. I am not using browser window of electron app in any case. So, I want want to open my auth0 authentication window in external browser(chrome,Firefox etc.) or installed default browser. Is there any way?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a few electron features here. First you need to open the Auth0 auth windows in the external browser using [this Electron api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31749625/make-a-link-from-electron-open-in-browser)

Then you login using your default browser and you must set in your redirection URL a custom protocol that points to your react app using [this Electron api](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appsetasdefaultprotocolclientprotocol-path-args), now you have the token in your Electron app.

Comment: thanks, but this approach don't work for linux. I need linux support too. Any workaround?

Comment: what part? opening the auth link in the default browser seems to be working -> https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/16149

The same for the protocol -> https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/6440

Comment: @Donflopez, great answer. That being said once I successfully authenticate in the browser with Auth0 and confirm opening the app using a deep link, the browser window still stays open. Do you know how to close the browser window previously triggered from an Electron app?

Comment: @AlexTamoykin I think you can only do it in a hacky way, for example, a simple one is running a command from the electron app to close the tab you'd like -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20441793/how-to-close-a-chrome-browser-tab-via-terminal

Comment: Good call, do you know how to choose which tab to close from an electron app? Looks like the app looses the context once you call shell.openExternal

Comment: @AlexTamoykin I'd inspect if you can change the tab title from Auht0 configuration and set something unique and that makes sense at the same time, to then close the tab with the command using the predicted title you set.

For example, you could send the tab title or a part of it the same way you send the token and then close the tab.

Answer (score 3):

#### Approach 1 (didn't work)

I tried the approach described in [@Donflopez's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56644597/2441655), and it got me half the way there.

The problem is that I'm using Google Auth for my app, and it doesn't support custom-protocols in the redirect url. (`Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Invalid scheme: my-custom-protocol://auth/handler`)

---

#### Approach 2 (didn't work)

My idea was then to use a redirect URI like this (with a NodeJS express server to receive the data): `http://localhost:XXXX/auth/handler`

Sign-in-tab opening code:

```
// not sure if this is the correct url to try, but it's what was opened when firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect() was called
require("electron").shell.openExternal(
    `https://${projectID}.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler`
    + `apiKey=${apiKey}&appName=%5BDEFAULT%5D&authType=signInViaRedirect`
    + `&providerId=google.com&scopes=profile&v=7.7.0`
    + `&redirectUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A${oauthPort}%2Fauth%2Fhandler`);
```

OAuth data receiver (NodeJS express server):

```
const express = require("express");
const oauthPort = XXXX;
const redirectServer = express();
redirectServer.get("/auth/handler", (req, res)=>{
    debugger;
    // I inspected the request data with debugger, but found nothing useful!
});
```

However, I wasn't able to get that working. While I was able to set up a NodeJS express server to try to receive the data, when the actual request came in (for `localhost:XXXX/auth/handler`, after the browser tab redirected to it), I didn't see anything in the request url or headers that looked like credential data.

If someone figures out how to extract/convert the request data into credential data, let me know! (In the meantime, I use the slightly more complex approach below.)

---

#### Approach 3 (worked)

My next idea (which works) was to just have my Electron app open a tab in an external browser, pointed to the same domain as in the Electron app, but to a special page that then launches the Google sign-in popup for the website:

```
require("electron").shell.openExternal(`${electronApp_domain}/sign-in-helper`);
```

(If your Electron page is served locally [eg. `file:///`], you may need to add a local express server to serve the sign-in-helper page for the external-browser tab -- not sure if Google sign-in works on `file:///` pages.)

That page then retrieves the Google id-token and access-token like so:

```
const firebase = require("firebase");
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(result=>{
    const idToken = result.credential.idToken;
    const accessToken = result.credential.accessToken;

    // You now have the id-token and access-token.
    // Either one is sufficient to sign-in your Electron app, just need to transfer it.
    TransferTokensToElectronApp(idToken, accessToken);
});
```

For transferring it to Electron, I did this:

```
const desktopApp_receiveTokensPort = XXXX;
function TransferTokensToElectronApp(idToken, accessToken) {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = `http://localhost:${desktopApp_receiveTokensPort}/receive-tokens/?idToken=${idToken}&accessToken=${accessToken}`;
    document.head.appendChild(script);

    // after 1s, remove the script element, and close the page
    setTimeout(()=>{
        script.remove();
        window.close();
    }, 1000);
}
```

And the receiving code in the Electron app:

```
const express = require("express");
const receiveTokensServer = express();
const receiveTokensPort = XXXX;
const receiveTokensServer_domainStr = `http://localhost:${receiveTokensPort}`;

receiveTokensServer.get("/receive-tokens", (req, res)=>{
    const url = new URL(`${receiveTokensServer_domainStr}/${req.url}`);
    const idToken = url.searchParams.get("idToken");
    const accessToken = url.searchParams.get("accessToken");

    console.log("Received sign-in data from web helper:", {idToken, accessToken});
    SendTokensToRenderer(idToken, accessToken);
});
receiveTokensServer.listen(receiveTokensPort);
```

Implementation of the `SendTokensToFrontEnd` function depends on how you perform communication in your app, but an example using Electron's [ipc system](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main#sending-messages):

```
function SendTokensToRenderer(idToken, accessToken) {
    browserWindow.webContents.send("token-transfer-channel", {idToken, accessToken});
}
```

And then finally, to receive those tokens in your renderer/frontend, and use it to sign-in to Firebase:

```
const {ipcRenderer} = require("electron");
const firebase = require("firebase");

ipcRenderer.on("token-transfer-channel", (event, data)=>{
    const cred = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(data.idToken, data.accessToken);
    firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(cred);
});
```

**EDIT**: Found a tutorial soon after, that uses a similar approach (except it transfers the credentials to the frontend through a shared database, rather than a `localhost` "script" request): https://pragli.com/blog/how-to-authenticate-with-google-in-electron