# Google Authentication with Firebase in an Electron app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, electron, google-oauth

I am having trouble getting Google OAuth to work in my Electron app. My initial research yielded these two articles:

- [How to authenticate with Google Oauth in Electron](https://pragli.com/blog/how-to-authenticate-with-google-in-electron/)
- [Using Firebase in Electron: Tips and Tricks](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/using-firebase-in-electron-tips-and-tricks-24ac5b44bf5a)

These seem to be the definitive sources after much debugging and Internet searches, though I cannot seem to get a working implementation.

I am currently creating the primary Electron window with the `webPreferences.nativeWindowOpen` option enabled.

```js
const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
        nativeWindowOpen: true,
    }
});
```

This is supposed to allow me to use `window.open()` from within the Electron renderer process so that I can leverage the user's native browser to avoid this error:

> Couldn’t sign you in
>
> This browser or app may not be secure. [Learn more](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7675428?hl=en)
>
> Try using a different browser. If you’re already using a supported browser, you can refresh your screen and try again to sign in.

I am also using `loadURL()` to load the contents of a React app.

```js
win.loadURL(
    isDev
        ? "http://localhost:3000"
        : `file://${path.join(__dirname, "../build/index.html")}`
);
```

Because I used `create-react-app` to create a boilerplate app, I'm already using Webpack as a bundler. However it is **very unclear** to me if there are configuration options I need to be setting to get Firebase to import the browser libraries. In the Tips and Tricks article, **Solution 1: Using a Bundler** basically says, "you should probably use a bundler, check the specific one you're using to make sure it's configured to prioritize the browser versions." That sounds great, but it is tremendously difficult to find information about how to deal with prioritizing `browswer` over `main` in general (it seems like that's what Webpack does depending on what the `target` is set to), and specifically I can't find any info on what I would need to do in my project to ensure this is happening. I've tried specifying `targert: "electron-renderer"` in my `package.json`, but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

The one thing I can say is that it doesn't seem like `window.open()` is actually taking me to my machine's native browser, it just opens up another window in Electron. That actually does seem to jive with the description of how Electron handles [opening windows](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/window-open), so I'm rather confused about where the native browser actually comes in. The only other seemingly useful [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62817382/6121611) I could find ultimately points back to the same original article I have been following from the start.

It seems like others tend to use the `electron.shell.openExternal()`, but I ran into errors when I tried to play with that, probably because it was in the renderer process, but I'm not certain. Also it seems like the this should be unnecessary based on the solution article's direct use of `window.open()`.

I've been able to implement everything up to **Step 3: Redirect the user to the browser
** in the Google OAuth tutorial, but I hit a brick wall after that because the popup window still isn't "a secure browser." If anyone could provide some insight it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could maybe try to spoof your user agent. Because that is what is firebease telling your "browser"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I am specifically trying to avoid that as Google has explicitly discouraged that. See the reference link in my original post.

Comment: I myself use firebase auth in my Electron app with no issues. Perhaps you have it set within the firebase console (or Google Console) to not allow localHost as a valid server requestor?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am having a similar problem...